# when I click on favorite icon button its changed whole list icon as a favorite

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Here is my code kindly tell me what I should do

'''  Container(
height: 200,
child: ListView.builder(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
itemCount: list.length,
shrinkWrap: true,
itemBuilder: (context, i) {
return InkWell(
onTap: () {
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => Fencyfunc(
image: list[i].toString(),
)));
},
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0),
child: Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
height: 200,
width: 150,
child: Stack(
children: [
Image.network(list[i],fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,),
Positioned(
right: 5,
top: 5,
child: IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
onPressed: () {
saveToMyList(list[i]);

```
                                              setState(() {
                                                istrue1 = !istrue1;
                                                istrue2 = !istrue2;
                                              });
                                            },
                                            color: !istrue1 && istrue2
                                                ? Colors.grey
                                                : !istrue2 && istrue1
                                                    ? Colors.red
                                                    : Colors.grey)),

                                ]
                            )
                        ),
                      ),
                    );}
              ),
            ),  '''
```

Comment: `tell me what I should do` - answer  for you as much detailed as question: fix this. post more code

Comment: Post the code for the list that got changed.

Comment: I edit my code you can see full code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add index in setState method so it will favourite only on particular index only